# Anchor Tag is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a body of email. Where I am giving a anchor tag  which supposed to show "TEXT" but instead of that it is showing url. Can anybody please help me in that.

My Code

```
MakeEmail : function(){
            var myObje = Ext.getCmp("MyObj");  // My Obj
        var Value = "3.14";
        var aTag = document.createElement("a");
            aTag.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
            aTag.innerText  = "w3Schools";
        window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Search :'+myObje.id+'&body=Please check Value'+Value+aTag
},
```

Comment: @Quentin This was asked 10 years back. I am damn sure there is some solution for that now

Comment: That doesn't mean the question isn't a duplicate, and nothing is stopping people adding answers to the existing question. A [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) can be used to attract new attention to an old question. (Anyway, there isn't a solution. No email client vendor has decided it is worth supporting mailto: URIs with HTML bodies)

Comment: Can I have bounty of duplicate question. If yes then I will go with bounty with this question after 48 hr.

Comment: You can offer a bounty on any (open) question you like. (There's no point though; what you want to achieve is still impossible).

Comment: Yes, I got it but still wondering even after billion of billion line of code in 10 years across the world, couldn't fix this issue :(

Comment: Because it requires that all the browser vendors and all the email client vendors collectively (a) decide that the good people will do with it will outweigh the evil (b) agree a way to do it (c) decide it is more important than any of the other things they want to do.

Comment: yes, agree. let me think some other thing to get out from this task. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`aTag.innerText` will give anchor text,

```js
var aTag = document.createElement("a");
aTag.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
aTag.innerText  = "w3Schools";
window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Search&body=Please check Value '+ encodeURIComponent(aTag.href)

console.log(aTag);
console.log(aTag.innerText); // this will give you anchor text
console.log(aTag.href);
```

Comment: Here it is working. But in my email body it is not coming.

Comment: I think following line should be,
window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Search :'+myObje.id+'&body=Please check Value'+Value+aTag
Instead try as follows,
window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Search :'+myObje.id+'&body=Please check Value'+Value+aTag.innerText

Comment: In this case it is displaying only text "w3school" No connection with link. :(

Comment: @David wants a fully operational anchor in the email.

Comment: @Yoda yes, This only my intention is.  Not getting any reason why it is challenging. Also one quick note in `aTag.outerhtml` I am getting only `"<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"></a>"`.

Comment: Weird, you should get everything, the docs say: "The outerHTML attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants."

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the code snippet above. You can not add html in mail body but you can add encoded url's which will be displayed as link in mail body. See if it satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Sure Thanks Jatin

Comment: @Jatinpatil Buddy in mai body I just want "w3Schools: with inline text. `encodeURIComponent(aTag.href)` doed not making any difference. well thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that anchor tags when cast to a string will output the value of the href. Presumably since this is the valuable information in the element.

If you run that code and inspect:

```
aTag.toString() // "https://www.w3schools.com/"
```

Remember that you are sending data through the URLs query string so an element cannot be sent in it's entirety. In order to work it must be cast to a string, javascript being loosely typed, does this automatically.

If you want the text, you need to use the same property you set it with

```
aTag.innerText
```

Comment: Can you tell what properties I need to set .

Comment: That largely depends on what exactly you're trying to do. But you should first look at the duplicate question highlighted as it appears to answer your question.

Comment: I am trying to give a "Text" with underline and on click of that opening URL. This is not duplicate. I already answer that

Comment: I understand, I was ensuring your intent hadn't changed given the emergence of new information. I am reading through the IETF standards docs, at first glance it seems like this is unchanged, even in ten years. The reason being security.

Comment: Ok. I am just curious about this. I need some solution therefore I am trying hard here. Also wondering how come this is a simple thing is not solvable.

Comment: I've provided a suggestion in my edit, but I have no idea how well it will work or if it will at all.

Comment: No that it is not at all correct. You can revert it to your old answer. Because in this case `anchor ` is a string. So it will take as a string.

Comment: The url is a string so the value which you append must too be a string.